# How to combine for and bulkinsert in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I was creating the following SQL to insert 10,000,000 records into the users_bobbies table.
However, it is too slow to proceed.
How can I introduce a bulk insert into this WHILE statement?
I would appreciate it if you could tell me.

Version: MySQL5.7

```
drop procedure if exists insert_user_hobby_data;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_user_hobby_data()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
    SET @user_counter = 0;
    WHILE @user_counter <= 9999999 DO
            set @user_id = @user_counter + 1;
            INSERT INTO users_bobbies (user_id, hobby_id)
            VALUES (@user_id, 1);
            SET @user_counter = @user_counter + 1;
        END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
CALL insert_user_hobby_data();
```

Comment: user_id is PRIMARY KEY ?

Comment: @SelVazi NO.user_id is not a primary key.

Comment: Put code into a transaction and commit every 10000 records or so instead of once..

Comment: If this task will be repeated, build a table with a million (or more) integers.  Then do `INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM ints;`

Answer (score 1):

This code got it running.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS bulk_insert;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE bulk_insert(IN len INT, IN block INT)
BEGIN
    SET @cnt = 0;
    loop1: LOOP
        SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO users_bobbies (user_id,hobby_id)VALUES';
        SET @i = 0;
        loop2: LOOP
            IF @cnt >= len THEN LEAVE loop1; END IF;
            SET @id = @cnt + 1;
            SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql, ' (', @id, ',', @cnt+1, ')');
            SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
            SET @i = @i + 1;
            IF @i < block AND @cnt < len THEN SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql, ',');
            ELSE LEAVE loop2; END IF;
        END LOOP loop2;
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END LOOP loop1;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
TRUNCATE users_bobbies; CALL bulk_insert(10000000, 1000);
```